# Installing nodejs 10 + npm on alpine linux

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, linux, docker, npm

I am using Alpine to build my Rails app and I am having some issues with some of its dependencies.

Right now, here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1-alpine
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.0.2

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        binutils-gold \
        build-base \
        curl \
        file \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        git \
        less \
        libstdc++ \
        libffi-dev \
        libc-dev \ 
        linux-headers \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libgcrypt-dev \
        make \
        netcat-openbsd \
        nodejs \
        openssl \
        pkgconfig \
        postgresql-dev \
        python \
        tzdata \
        yarn 

RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.2
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle check || bundle install

COPY . /myapp
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "80"]
```

My `entrypoint.sh` file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
bundle install
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
npm install
set -e

rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

exec "$@"
```

When it comes to `npm install`, I have issues trying to install `puppeteer@3.0.0` (can't use 3.1.0 because of another error).

Here's the error when installing 3.1.0:

```
/myapp # npm install puppeteer@3.1.0

> puppeteer@3.1.0 install /myapp/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

/myapp/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js:175
            } catch {
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@3.1.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@3.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-26T01_19_13_984Z-debug.log
```

Based on the lack of success getting 3.1.0 installed [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5909), I was informed to try 3.0.0

So when trying to install 3.0.0, the following happens:

```
/myapp # npm install puppeteer@3.0.0

> puppeteer@3.0.0 install /myapp/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

(node:111) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): The "original" argument must be of type function
(node:111) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
+ puppeteer@3.0.0
added 4 packages in 1.264s
```

According to [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5687), the node version is old. Currently, I am running nodejs `8.9.3`, as shown here:

```
/myapp # node -v
v8.9.3
```

I tried to install `nodejs-current`, but it seems like it *uninstalled* npm.

```
/myapp # apk add nodejs-current
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/3) Purging nodejs-npm (8.9.3-r1)
(2/3) Purging nodejs (8.9.3-r1)
(3/3) Installing nodejs-current (9.2.1-r1)
Executing busybox-1.27.2-r11.trigger
OK: 300 MiB in 87 packages
/myapp # node -v
v9.2.1
/myapp # npm install puppeteer@3.0.0
/bin/sh: npm: not found
```

How can I upgrade my nodejs version without uninstalling npm? If I try to install npm again, the following error occurs:

```
/myapp # apk add npm
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  npm (missing):
    required by: world[npm]
/myapp # apk add --update npm
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  npm (missing):
    required by: world[npm]
```

Comment: What if you change these `COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile` ,`COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock` then `WORKDIR /myapp`

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram same thing happens.

Comment: What about adding `apk add npm` in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I get the `ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:` error @SachithMuhandiram when running that

Comment: How does Node fit into this application stack otherwise?  Can you use a multi-stage build to assemble a front-end based on a `node:lts` image, then `COPY` that into the final application?

Comment: The rails app uses puppeteer from Google to generate PDF documents and so it requires node to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the required version for node like you did with  ruby, `FROM ruby:2.5.1-alpine` , in the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml file otherwise accordingly.

Check this [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) for the suitable version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the update version of `ruby` which has the upgraded version of `alpine kernel`. For an e.g., you can use `ruby:2.5.3-alpine3.9`

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3-alpine3.9
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.0.2

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        binutils-gold \
        build-base \
        curl \
        file \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        git \
        less \
        libstdc++ \
        libffi-dev \
        libc-dev \ 
        linux-headers \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libgcrypt-dev \
        make \
        netcat-openbsd \
        nodejs \
        npm \
        openssl \
        pkgconfig \
        postgresql-dev \
        python \
        tzdata \
        yarn 

RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.2
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle check || bundle install
```

and output of few commands

```
/ # npm -v
6.4.1
/ # node -v
v10.14.2
/ # cat /etc/issue
Welcome to Alpine Linux 3.9
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
```